# How can one see Mono's jitted code?

Tags: .net, mono, jit

Jitted code can be easily viewed in case of .NET Framework using Visual Studio (Debug > Windows > Disassembly). How can one see jitted code on Mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see jitted code, `mono -v -v` can be used.